# Policies and Procedures Database

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a database for work purpose, and I need you guys to help me. I don't know if my idea possible or not but i want to give a chance to apply it.

As the title I want to make database for all policies and procedures in our organization. The purposes of this database are whenever my manager want to review any policy he can search for the policy by keyword, or title, or the code of each policy, also in order to make any change on that policy, he can review, edit the policy and print it. While he doing some changing on a specific policy I want to keep the original policy as well, so if I want to make a historical report for that policy I can generate all changes happens on that policy, the original one, the first change, the second change and so on.

What I want to is creating a " Master Table " Consist of all updated Policies for "  4 Departments " and I want to create a separate tables for each department. And then create a relationship between all those table, (all of them link with the Policy code column -if possible-). So, whenever the user enter data from the displayed form, this data will be record in master table, and the entered data will be saved in the related department table ( if he enter a data related to the department 1, the data will be saved in the master table and the department 1 table, and etc. ). So the result of all of these are whenever I want to make a report for all entered policies I can generate it from the master table, and whenever I want to make a separate report for each policy I can do that too.

My question is, if this database possible to be create, how i can create it, where I faced a lot of problems while I tried to create it, and if it's not possible, What should I do in order to get that features that my manager want?

Waiting your response.

The Features that I want to be exist are:
1- Display the policy in proper formatting (Making a Report)
2- Editing an existing policy.
3- Adding New Policy.
4- Make a historical report for each policy.
5- Searching bar to be search by keyword, title, policy code, and column name
6- Printing that policy
7- all document should be different by the unique version number.

Answer (score 0):

If this were my project, I would run away from MS Access. A content management system or wiki would be a better choice - formatting and versioning are built in and you don't have to code it from the ground up.